# Set BindByName in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have problem with bind variables (to be specyfic with its default setting BindByPosition). For example, I have procedure such as:

```
DECLARE
    v_sql varchar2;
BEGIN
    v_sql := 'select :1 as field1, :1 as field2 from dual';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING 'test', 'test';
END;
```

Now I need to type 'test' twice. How can I change BindByName to true, to have procedure like this:

```
DECLARE
    v_sql varchar2;
BEGIN
    v_sql := 'select :1 as field1, :1 as field2 from dual';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING 'test';
END;
```

Comment: When you try to put two place holders in your dynamic query then certainly it would need two bind variable. It cannot be changed to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use repeating placeholders in dynamic sql, only in pl/sql.

More in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need dynamic SQL for your example:

```
DECLARE
  val    VARCHAR2(20) := 'Test';
  field1 VARCHAR2(20);
  field2 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  SELECT val, val
  INTO   field1, field2
  FROM   DUAL;
END;
/
```

or, without the SQL:

```
DECLARE
  val    VARCHAR2(20) := 'Test';
  field1 VARCHAR2(20);
  field2 VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  field1 := val;
  field2 := val;
END;
/
```